# How does dynamic method dispatch actually function?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Given two classes A and B inherits from A such as :

```
public class A{
   public void run(){
      System.out.println("This is A");
   }
}

public class B extends A{
   @Override
   public void run(){
      System.out.println("This is B");
   }
}

public class Dispatch{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      A var = new B();
      var.run(); // prints : This is B
   }
}
```

How could Java be able to tell which method `run()` at runtime should make a call for since the object referenced by `var` contains (i.e. has a pointer in the method area to) both methods `A#run()` and `B#run()`? Does Java run some in depth search algorithm for the object tree representation to resolve which method should be called or what does happen actually behind the scenes in dynamic polymorphism?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678928/how-does-java-determine-methods-call-at-runtime-in-polymorphism

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Java pick which overloaded function to call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385551/how-does-java-pick-which-overloaded-function-to-call)